# Не могу изменить высоту Row, при нахождении Grid внутри другого контейнера

Tags: wpf

У меня есть идея сделать сайт с вертикальной прокруткой. Самый простой способ - который я себе придумал - использовать StackPanel внутри ScrollView, внутрь которой расположить картинки с бэкграундами сайта (Тот вариант, что я - дно, я не исключаю). Но поскольку помимо картинок мне ещё нужны и кнопки, и другие элементы, я решил картинки заменить Grid, дабы подружить элементы с изменением размера страницы.

Собственно, проблема. При использовании Column я имею возможность задавать ширину колонки, однако при попытке провернуть тоже самое с Row я терплю фиаско. Высота строки автоматически задаётся в половину от высоты Grid, и изменений не слушается. Если оставить *, то она будет сохранять отношение 1*, не обращая внимания на введёное значение (5*,10*,100*). Если её убрать, то высота изменяться будет, но будет отсчитываться от центра. Если поставить Auto, то ячейка уползет вверх.

```xaml
<Page x:Class="WpfBrowserApp1.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfBrowserApp1"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="1612" d:DesignWidth="1867"
      Title="Page1"
      SizeChanged="Page_SizeChanged">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel Name="ListView" CanVerticallyScroll="True" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="402*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="114*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="169*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1149*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="Resources/6.jpg" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1"  Opacity=".5"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="3"  Opacity=".5"/>
            </Grid>
            <Image Source="Resources/2.jpg"></Image>
            <Image Source="Resources/3.jpg"></Image>
            <Image Source="Resources/4.jpg"></Image>
            <Image Source="Resources/5.jpg"></Image>
            <Image Source="Resources/6.jpg"></Image>
            <Image Source="Resources/7.jpg"></Image>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

[image]

Comment: то, что задается для ширины и высоты Grid в виде звездочек - (Width="402*") это коэффициент важности, то есть если у вас например две строки и ставите   "<RowDefinition Height="4*"/><RowDefinition Height="2*" />", то вы можете сократить на 2 без изменения результата.

Comment: но вообще говоря не совсем понятно в чем именно проблема